# Array sequence (string) returns the next visible button - React

Tags: arrays, reactjs, button, react-functional-component

[image]

LINK CODE :[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-puzzle-drag-and-drop-9g4y6)

Through Drag and Drop I assemble a sequence that is const correctSequence = ["task-5", "task-3", "task-2", "task-1", "task-4"]; My current button is disabled when the sequence is right it changes to enabled

Comment: Please post your code here with a specific question about what part you need help with.

Comment: That doesn't really help. Put the code you need help with in the question, explain what you're expecting, and what it's doing instead.

Comment: I'm just trying to give you advice. The best way to get help here is to put your code in the question and explain exactly which part you need help with.

Comment: @Bafsky Thanks for the tip, but in this case I used some props between components so I left the example on the Demo link. But in short I have a <button disabled = {disabled}> Next </button> with useState = const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState (true); Then I created a const with the correct order of the sequence: const correctSequence = ["task-5", "task-3", "task-2", "task-1", "task-4"]; The question now is how do I check the sequence and if it is right leave the button enabled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just missing to set enable and disable action when its correct

```
 useEffect(() => {
    console.log(state.columns["column-2"].taskIds, correctSequence);

    if(JSON.stringify(state.columns["column-2"].taskIds) === JSON.stringify(correctSequence)){
      setDisabled(false);
    }else {
      setDisabled(true);
    }
  }, [state]);
```

This code will check if order column is equal your correct sequence or not, if its not correct then disable else enable it

final code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { DragDropContext } from "react-beautiful-dnd";
import Column from "./Column";
import { Typography, Button } from "@material-ui/core";
import { initialData } from "./initial-data";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

// ESTYLES MATERIAL UI
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    overflow: "hidden",
    backgroundColor: "#EBE9E9"
  },
  box: {
    border: "2px solid #EBE9E9",
    height: "auto",
    marginBottom: "36px",
    backgroundColor: "#EBE9E9"
  },
  paper: {
    maxWidth: 560,
    margin: `${theme.spacing(1)}px auto`,
    backgroundColor: "#EBE9E9",
    boxShadow: ["none"]
  },
  button: {
    color: "#000000",
    backgroundColor: "#ffdd03",
    borderRadius: "30px",
    fontWeight: 500,
    fontFamily: "Rubik",
    fontSize: "15px",
    marginTop: "10px",
    boxShadow:
      "0px 3px 1px -2px rgb(0 0 0 / 20%), 0px 2px 2px 0px rgb(0 0 0 / 14%), 0px 1px 5px 0px rgb(0 0 0 / 12%)",
    "&:hover": {
      backgroundColor: "#ffff54"
    },
    "&:active": {
      backgroundColor: "#ffff54",
      boxShadow: "none"
    }
  },
  disabled: {}
}));

const App = (props) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(initialData);
  const classes = useStyles();

  // buttond disabled
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(true);

  // sequence correct
  const correctSequence = ["task-5", "task-3", "task-2", "task-1", "task-4"];

  const onDragEnd = (result) => {
    const { destination, source, draggableId } = result;

    if (!destination) {
      return;
    }

    if (
      destination.droppableId === source.droppableId &&
      destination.index === source.index
    ) {
      return;
    }

    const start = state.columns[source.droppableId];
    const finish = state.columns[destination.droppableId];

    if (start === finish) {
      const newTaskIds = Array.from(start.taskIds);
      newTaskIds.splice(source.index, 1);
      newTaskIds.splice(destination.index, 0, draggableId);

      const newColumn = {
        ...start,
        taskIds: newTaskIds
      };

      const newState = {
        ...state,
        columns: {
          ...state.columns,
          [newColumn.id]: newColumn
        }
      };

      setState(newState);
      return;
    }

    // Moving from one list to another
    const startTaskIds = Array.from(start.taskIds);
    startTaskIds.splice(source.index, 1);
    const newStart = {
      ...start,
      taskIds: startTaskIds
    };

    const finishTaskIds = Array.from(finish.taskIds);
    finishTaskIds.splice(destination.index, 0, draggableId);
    const newFinish = {
      ...finish,
      taskIds: finishTaskIds
    };

    const newState = {
      ...state,
      columns: {
        ...state.columns,
        [newStart.id]: newStart,
        [newFinish.id]: newFinish
      }
    };
    setState(newState);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(state.columns["column-2"].taskIds, correctSequence);

    if(JSON.stringify(state.columns["column-2"].taskIds) === JSON.stringify(correctSequence)){
      setDisabled(false);
    }else {
      setDisabled(true);
    }
  }, [state]);

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Paper className={classes.paper}>
        <DragDropContext onDragEnd={onDragEnd}>
          <div title="EDUCAÇÃO BÁSICA">
            {state.columnOrder.map((columnId) => {
              const column = state.columns[columnId];
              const tasks = column.taskIds.map((taskId) => state.tasks[taskId]);
              return <Column key={column.id} column={column} tasks={tasks} />;
            })}
          </div>
        </DragDropContext>
        <Typography align="center">
          <Button
            variant="contained"
            disabled={disabled}
            className={classes.button}
          >
            Next
          </Button>
        </Typography>
      </Paper>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help the code worked perfectly, I hadn't thought of checking the column, you are a genius :)

Comment: Apper: React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'correctSequence'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. (react-hooks/exhaustive-deps)

Comment: Yup, you can add it, but since its const, its will not be make any change else if its will be change in future...

Comment: I put the following code and now the error is not showing anymor:  // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, [state]);